# An instance of a view in ios

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having a difficulty understanding what `output.text` means. I think my understanding is that output is an instance of the class UIViewController and `text` is a variable defined in this class. Is this correct? Also, in the function, `consoleOut()`, why should one do `output.text = output.text + text` instead of `output.text = text`?

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Guessing Game
//
//  Created by Jae Hyun Kim on 8/6/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jae Hyun Kim. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var output: UITextView!
    var guesses : UInt = 0;
    var number : UInt = 0;
    var gameover = false;
    let MAX_GUESSES = 8;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func consoleOut(text : String) {
        output.text = output.text + text;
    }

    @IBAction func guess(sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`output` is a `UITextView` that is defined in the view (the file that shows what screen will appear to the user). So you are correct in saying that `text` is a variable of the `UITextView` class.

Additionally, `output.text = output.text + text` will *append* `text` to the existing text in `output.text`. This is unlike `output.text = text` which will overwrite whatever was already in `output.text` with the new `text`.

Comment: When you say output is a UITextView, are you saying that output is an instance of UITextView?